# Cannot convert Premium_Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I have an android fragment where a user can make an in-app purchase, but when I'm trying to compile it, I get this error:

> error: incompatible types: Premium_Fragment cannot be converted to Activity.

I used this [github page](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) as reference for for implementing In-app purchases.

```
btn_influencer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               bp.purchase(Premium_Fragment.this, "channel");
        }
    });
```

This line cause the problem:
          `bp.purchase(Premium_Fragment.this, "channel");`

Comment: Probably because `Premium_Fragment` (why is there a `_`?) is not an Activity, it's a Fragment. Have you tried `getActivity()`?

Answer (score 0):

As per the github link its asking for Activity only like below

bp.purchase(YOUR_ACTIVITY, "YOUR PRODUCT ID FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE");

we can't give fragment i guess. Try creating the activity and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Premium_Fragment.this` to `getActivity()`. `getActivity()` in a Fragment returns the Activity the Fragment is currently associated with.